# iOS Swift: NSBlockOperation behaves differently on iPhone simulator 6s and 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsblockoperation

I found it strange to see the different behaviors for my `NSBlockOperation` in updating the UI in my app.

For each of the `UIButtons` (e.g. Thumb-up, Thumb-down, Like, etc), I have them linked to their action method which is similar to the one below using `NSBlockOperation`.

Take the **Like** button for example:

```
@IBAction func likePost(sender: AnyObject) {
        favoriteBtn.enabled = false
        let operation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in

            NetworkUtils.sharedInstance.likePost(self.curPost) { (completed, error) -> Void in
                self.favoriteBtn.enabled = true
                self.updateUserLabels(completed) // does not get triggered
            }
        }

        operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
    }
```

The `NetworkUtils` makes an API call to **Parse** that returns a closure for `completed` (Bool) and `error` (String?). In this `NSBlockOperation`, I use the `self.updateUserLabels()` method to update the UI on `mainQueue`:

```
func updateUserLabels(completed: Bool) {

        if completed {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
                self.likeCount.text = self.curPost.likes; 
            }
        }
    }
```

The code works well and as expected in the **iPhone simulator 5s**, however, on the simulator 6s or 6s Plus, it takes much longer to see the `Like` button to be re-enabled, and the `updateUserLabels()` method gets called even before the `NetworkUtils.sharedInstance.likeQuestion()` call returns the closure.

I was wondering why there is such a difference on different iPhone simulators, and how to make them work the same way like on 5s?

Answer (score 1):

> it takes much longer to see the Like button to be re-enabled

This is almost certainly because you have neglected to step out to the *main thread* when performing an operation that involves the interface. Your whole issue would thus presumably be a threading problem.

Comment: but it works fast and well on iPhone simulator 5s, the problem only exists on 6s or 6s plus.

Comment: That sort of inconsistency is the very essence of threading problems.